# Hidden minecart trail

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Well, in another part of my map, I want to make a walking armor stand walking across the player, but I don't want to do every rotation of the armor stand, so I decided to use Invisible minecart with a walking pose of armor stand.

How do I make the minecart rail (not minecart but minecart rail) hidden or invisible to the player?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way as far as I know of doing that. You could move the minecart every tick with fast command block clock and command blocks but it would generate massive lags (if you have weak computer) and would require you to use relative coordinates and scoreboards to compact the machine without a command block for every move. I've tried it on my world and well... got stuck at basic machine that moved minecart for 5 ticks forward by 0.25 of the block and then turned it by 90 deegrees left. Saddly this is not an option for console edition (if you are talking about console edition)

---

You could also use mods.